# JMS Application Publish Subscribe

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb, jms, publish-subscribe

I have done the following tutorial on Publish/Subscribe Model with Message-Driven Beans and GlassFish Server. Visit http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/JMS_pub_sub/JMS_pub_sub.html However i would now like to change code such that the Subscriber can change its subscription at any time.

I have analysed the code on the subscriber side that the subscription set once on top but cannot find where i can put the change of subscription code Since the Specific EJB is alive whenever a matching region is used in the web page.

Am i on the right track. If not please provide feedback if have failed to understand concept. A solution is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "change its subscription"? Change from what to what?

Comment: The user should be able to choose for which region message it can get. At the moment if the subscriber is subscribed to region A then he cannot Change the region To B @Mike

Comment: There are ways to achieve this, but none are particularly straightforward. The reason you would need to subscribe to specific regions is for different behaviour in handling that region's message. If that's not necessary, then why have region as an ActivationConfigProperty at all? `Region` could simply be part of the message.

Comment: Assume all clients to have same back-end behavior control. What i want is the client should able to change its region that it is listening to and get messages for the new region only . Thus need to change its subscription @Mike

Comment: You could achieve the same result with each client implementing an MDB for each region (as the example shows). A single client may have multiple MDBs without an issue and a topic-based pub/sub pattern means that all subscribers would receive all messages without any issues. While there are ways to change these properties, *all* involve the MDB being recreated (effectively a redeploy). You are not limited to a single MDB, though, so this shouldn't be a problem.